# In Epiode 378 of One Piece, what is the first song that Brook played?

Tags: one-piece

I know this song was played in other times of the series, but this time it caught my attention.

edit: The time is around 14:30
edit: It's used as background music in most of the comedic parties that the characters have in One Piece.

Comment: is it [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gHeLXat1QM) song?

Comment: nope, I mean the one before it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The song is called **Minato Mura**.

After some additional searching I found that the piano solo is part of the song called **Village Harbour** (or Minato Mura in Japanese), which is supposed to be part of the second song of the second OST collection as shown on [Youtube](http://youtu.be/QZA5qCfRZQc?t=1m17s)

---

More information:

- [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chILw64HZMw)
- Piano sheet on [Everyonepiano](http://www.everyonepiano.com/Music-2670-Minato-Mura---One-Piece-OST.html)